# Is there a Visual Studio (or freeware) equivalent for Expression Blend's "Edit Template" feature?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, templates, expression-blend

In Expression Blend, you can view and edit the control template of objects in the "Objects and Timeline" panel. I'm wondering if there's an equivalent feature in Visual Studio or if there's something free (or very inexpensive) I can download that will allow me to do this.

Doing this for `DataGrid` results in the following:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGrid}">
  ...
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Custom:DataGrid}">
      ...
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(The `...` is of course replaced with setters and the contents of the control template.)

This is a very useful starting point if you want to create a custom style and template for a control. It seems like you can do pretty much anything you can do in Blend in Studio, but this one is eluding me. Any ideas?

**Edit**

I'm also curious if this feature will be in Visual Studio 2010. Anyone know?

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted them and replaced them with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[The SimpleStyles project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771597.aspx)

Try that I think it would be the same. It gives you the simplest template for each control, so you can use it as a jump-off point.

Code for project to get templates:

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Xml;

namespace ControlTemplateBrowser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon icon;
        private WindowState _storedWindowState;
        private bool _ballonShownOnce = false;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Type controlType = typeof(Control);

            List<Type> derivedTypes = new List<Type>();

            // Search all the types in the assembly where the Control class is defined
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Control));

            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                // Only add a type of the list if it's a Control, a concrete class, and public.
                if (type.IsSubclassOf(controlType) && !type.IsAbstract && type.IsPublic)
                {
                    derivedTypes.Add(type);
                }
            }

            // Sort the types. The custom TypeComparer class orders types alphabetically by type name.
            derivedTypes.Sort(new TypeComparer());
            lstTypes.ItemsSource = derivedTypes;

            SetupTrayIcon();
        }

        private void lstTypes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the selected type.
                Type type = (Type)lstTypes.SelectedItem;

                // Instantiate the type
                ConstructorInfo info = type.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes);
                Control control = (Control)info.Invoke(null);

                // Add it to the grid (but keep it hidden)
                control.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                grid.Children.Add(control);

                // Get the template.
                ControlTemplate template = control.Template;

                // Get the XAML for the template.
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings);
                XamlWriter.Save(template, writer);

                // Display the template
                txtTemplate.Text = sb.ToString();
                grid.Children.Remove(control);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                txtTemplate.Text = "<< Error generating template: " + err.Message + ">>";
            }
        }

        #region System tray icon code

        private void SetupTrayIcon()
        {
            // Add system tray icon
            icon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
            icon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("appIcon.ico");
            icon.BalloonTipIcon = System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info;
            icon.BalloonTipTitle = "Minimized to tray";
            icon.BalloonTipText = "Click icon to maximize.";
            icon.Visible = false;
            icon.Click += new EventHandler(icon_Click);
        }

        private void icon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Show();
            WindowState = _storedWindowState;
        }

        private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            {
                Hide();
                if (icon != null)
                {
                    if (!_ballonShownOnce)
                    {
                        icon.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
                        _ballonShownOnce = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                _storedWindowState = WindowState;
        }

        private void Window_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (icon != null)
                icon.Visible = !IsVisible;
        }

        private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            icon.Visible = false;
            icon.Dispose();
            icon = null;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class TypeComparer : IComparer<Type>
    {
        #region IComparer<Type> Members

        public int Compare(Type x, Type y)
        {
            return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
        }

        #endregion
    }

}
```

WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="ControlTemplateBrowser.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WPF Control Template Browser" Height="600" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Icon="/ControlTemplateBrowser;component/appIcon.png" Closed="Window_Closed" StateChanged="Window_StateChanged" IsVisibleChanged="Window_IsVisibleChanged">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="8">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lstTypes" SelectionChanged="lstTypes_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtTemplate" Text="Select a control to see its template." VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Copy paste this into your project and do the necessary namespace modifications. I think what you'll need to modify is this part:

```
// Search all the types in the assembly where the Control class is defined
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Control));
```

To get the controls from a different assembly. Let if you tried it, and how it went.

Comment: Nice, but that only includes the templates for built-in controls. Expression Blend seems to be able to extract the template even for library controls. In the example I used, `DataGrid` is actually part of the WPF Toolkit.

Comment: Ah you're right. I'll past some code that might help you get these templates. It only works for built in controls, but maybe you can find a way to extend it to get the templates of other controls you need.

Comment: No problem. Btw, here's an image of what it looks like http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/6681/templatebrowser.png